# Where should extensions be placed to be included in a custom build of firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-addons

I am trying to create a custom installer for firefox which will include an extension that I created myself, however, I am unable to find the correct place to put the zipped extension file in the source so that it will be included in the installation automatically.

I am following the instructions [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/repackaging-windows-installer), but I do not know where to place the extension.

I tried creating a directory core/distribution/extensions, but that did not work either.

I am pretty new at this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice in the Mozilla Support article
[Deploying Firefox with extensions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/deploying-firefox-with-extensions):

- Create the directory `distribution\extensions`
- Find the
  [*add-on ID*](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/extensions-and-the-add-on-id/) for each extension that you wish to add to this directory
- Either:

  - Add the `.xpi` files of the extensions to this directory, each
    renamed to the extension *add-on ID*, while keeping the `.xpi` extension, or
  - Create in `extensions` a directory named *add-on ID*
    and unzip the extension into it.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this solution, but when I ran the repacked installer, the add-on was not found at all. In order to test the process, I changed one setting by adding a file in the browser/defaults/preferences directory, and that setting was changed when I used the custom installer, but the extension was not picked up. Any other idea?

Comment: Actually, upon further digging, I realized that the extension is being found and presented in the installed files, yet the extension is not actually installed in the browser.

Comment: In the link I can see a reference to the preference `extensions.installDistroAddons`  that should be set to `true`. You could check that.

Comment: Thank you again, I changed that preference, but the add on was still not being added to the browser automatically on startup, though it still is in the files which are installed and I verified that extensions.installDistroAddons is set to true

Comment: I looked in the browser console, and I found that it was not loading the add-on because I was using a folder containing the unzipped xpi, and it was expecting a .xpi file. I am going to try with the .xpi file

Comment: I used the .xpi file and that error disappeared, but it still did not load the add-on automatically

Comment: Actually, it works, the issue was that I was working on a machine that already had profiles installed. When I tried it on a fresh machine, it was included and loaded automatically

Comment: Good, I was worried that something was missing from the documentation. Enjoy.